# How create entity. Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, one-to-one

Each company has two properties, they are company name and estimated annual earnings.
There are two types of companies: 1- Main company, 2 - Subsidiary company.
The company can belong only to one company but can have a few child companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `@Entity` you define a class to become an entity. with `@Column` you define which attributes map to which table columns. After that you need to define your relationships, in this case a self reference to the same table (parent company to child company), you can define it like this:

```
@ManyToOne
private Company parentCompany;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCompany", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Company> childCompanies;
```

Comment: There are many of them, so it should be named `childCompanies`. Naming is crucial. Why use FetchType EAGER instead of using the sane default, especially for a recursive association like this. Loading any cmpany will force the loading of the whole company tree.

Comment: thanks i edited the name, but for the fetch type i usually use eager for better performance :) in my answer it is a hint that you can control how to fetch relationships.

Comment: Using EAGER for toMany associations is the best way to ruin the performance

Comment: I guess not. what if you want to do some repetitive operation on childCompanies :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to set you in the right direction, you need to look at association mapping, Hibernate provides field/method annotation for defining associations - of particular note in your case;

```
@Entity
@OneToMany
@ManyToOne
```

I'd recommend taking some time to familiarize yourself with the [Hibernate Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html) on the subject; it's fundamental to using hibernate.  Google for some starer tutorials on the subject to get you started - there are so many out there ([here for example](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-annotations-1.html)).  I'm sure you can get more help if you run into specific problems when you get started.